# $|f''(\xi)|=\frac{4|f(b)-f(a)|}{(b-a)^2}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> Let $f$ be twice differentiable, and $f'(b)=-f'(a)$. Show there exists $\xi\in(a,b)$, such that $|f''(\xi)|=\frac{4|f(b)-f(a)|}{(b-a)^2}$.

My attempt: Taylor expansion at $a$, $b$, using $f(\frac{a+b}{2})$. But substracting will not give a sum in $f''$! So...what to do?

Comment: Is this even true? Take $a=-1, b=1, f(x)=x^2$.